# Does a list of which books gutenberg has in both english and spanish exist?

Tags: traducción

I am learning Spanish primarily by having a Spanish and English copy of the same book, and reading them simultaneously (literally (no pun intended) with one in each hand).

http://www.gutenberg.org has mostly English books, but a few Spanish, too. Does a list of which books gutenberg has in both english and spanish exist? The only one I know of as of now is Don Quixote.

Comment: google can help you better

Comment: I tried that; googling "which books does gutenberg have in spanish and english" gave me no exhiliration.

Comment: The Alchemist/El alquimista

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The Alchemist/El alquimista
- The Godfather /El Padrino
- Sophie's World/ El mundo de Sofía
- Les Misérables/Los Miserables
- The Davice Code/El código de Da Vinci
- Love in the Time of Cholera/El amor en tiempos de cólera

Comment: These are all available on gutenberg? IOW, they are in the public domain? I imagine Les Misérables, but the others I'm familiar with seem too new for that to be the case.

Comment: I have seen in elnglish/spanish those books you can find them in the web...

Comment: search on amazon

Comment: I appreciate the info, but the question was, which pairs are available on gutenberg.org, IOW which are in the public domain. So I upvoted your answer but have not marked it as *the* answer for that reason.

Comment: it's ok, yo have to goolge it

Comment: We seem to be going around in circles; my response to your original comment addresses that.